# Rearrange dataframe using dcast using a dummy

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2

I've like to use dcast function (reshape2 package) for returns a reshape data frame, but doesn't work. In my example:

```
#Data set
X<-c(804519.4,804519.6,804519.6,804519.4,804519.4,804519.4,804519.6,804519.6,804519.4,804519.4)
Y<-c(7673833,7673833,7673833,7673833,7673833,7673833,7673833,7673833,7673833,7673833)
band<-c("band1","band1","band1","band1","band1","band2","band2","band2","band2","band2")# My original data set are 31 bands
reflec<-c(9.608848,10.504454,8.648237,9.935091,11.282750,9.608848,10.504454,8.648237,9.935091,11.282750)
dummy<-1:10
RES3<-data.frame(X,Y,band,reflec,dummy)
RES3
          X       Y  band    reflec dummy
1  804519.4 7673833 band1  9.608848     1
2  804519.6 7673833 band1 10.504454     2
3  804519.6 7673833 band1  8.648237     3
4  804519.4 7673833 band1  9.935091     4
5  804519.4 7673833 band1 11.282750     5
6  804519.4 7673833 band2  9.608848     6
7  804519.6 7673833 band2 10.504454     7
8  804519.6 7673833 band2  8.648237     8
9  804519.4 7673833 band2  9.935091     9
10 804519.4 7673833 band2 11.282750    10
RES3<-as.data.frame(RES3)
colnames(RES3)<-c("X","Y","band","reflec","dummy")
dcast(RES3, X + Y + dummy ~ band,
         fun.aggregate = length,
         value.var="reflec")
```

Doesn't work, my output is:

```
          X       Y dummy band1 band2
1  804519.4 7673833     1     1     0
2  804519.4 7673833     4     1     0
3  804519.4 7673833     5     1     0
4  804519.4 7673833     6     0     1
5  804519.4 7673833     9     0     1
6  804519.4 7673833    10     0     1
7  804519.6 7673833     2     1     0
8  804519.6 7673833     3     1     0
9  804519.6 7673833     7     0     1
10 804519.6 7673833     8     0     1
```

I expected:

```
         X       Y    band1    band2      
1 804519.4 7673833    9.608848 9.608848    
2 804519.6 7673833   10.504454 10.504454   
3 804519.6 7673833    8.648237  8.648237   
4 804519.4 7673833    9.935091  9.935091   
5 804519.4 7673833   11.282750 11.282750
```

Any member could help me, because my original data set are 31 bands as levels and I've like to convert in columns? Thanks!

Comment: `reshape2` has been deprecated in favor of `tidyr` FYI: https://github.com/cran/reshape2

Comment: Also, why the lines for `as.data.frame` and `colnames`? You've already got a data frame with those column names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like I mentioned, `reshape2` has been [deprecated](https://github.com/cran/reshape2) in favor of `tidyr` within the `tidyverse` packages. In my opinion (and that of the packages' authors), `tidyr`'s `spread` and `gather` are a bit more clear than `reshape2`'s `cast` and `melt`—no formula notation, cleaner ways to specify values. (Some context for that is [here](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/#related-work)).

Also as I mentioned, you've got a couple extra lines—`data.frame` will add the column names according to the names of the vectors going into it.

I've updated this answer to match the new data you posted. My original solution worked for your original data, but needs some more steps for your new data, which I'm doing with `dplyr` functions.

I don't totally get the `dummy` column at this point, since it's not in your expected output. I'm dropping it with `dplyr::select(-dummy)`. One tricky thing with `tidyr::spread` is that you need some way to mark rows uniquely—annoying, but also prevents errors in reshaping the data. So I'm grouping by `band`, then adding row numbers as follows:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

res3 <- data.frame(X, Y, band, reflec, dummy)

res3 %>%
  select(-dummy) %>%
  group_by(band) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number())
#> # A tibble: 10 x 5
#> # Groups:   band [2]
#>          X       Y band  reflec   row
#>      <dbl>   <dbl> <fct>  <dbl> <int>
#>  1 804519. 7673833 band1   9.61     1
#>  2 804520. 7673833 band1  10.5      2
#>  3 804520. 7673833 band1   8.65     3
#>  4 804519. 7673833 band1   9.94     4
#>  5 804519. 7673833 band1  11.3      5
#>  6 804519. 7673833 band2   9.61     1
#>  7 804520. 7673833 band2  10.5      2
#>  8 804520. 7673833 band2   8.65     3
#>  9 804519. 7673833 band2   9.94     4
#> 10 804519. 7673833 band2  11.3      5
```

That way, row 1 will have a band 1 value and a band 2 value, and so on. Then I call `spread` with the band as the key to become columns and the reflec values to populate those columns, and finally drop the row number column.

```r
res3 %>%
  select(-dummy) %>%
  group_by(band) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  spread(key = band, value = reflec) %>%
  select(-row)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#>         X       Y band1 band2
#>     <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 804519. 7673833  9.61  9.61
#> 2 804519. 7673833  9.94  9.94
#> 3 804519. 7673833 11.3  11.3 
#> 4 804520. 7673833 10.5  10.5 
#> 5 804520. 7673833  8.65  8.65
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

The `value.var` should be a string that specifies the column name.  According to `?dcast`

> value.var - name of column which stores values

and `name` of column is character string

By specifying it unquoted, it is searching for the column name from the values

```
dcast(RES3, X + Y + dummy ~ band,
         fun.aggregate = length,
         value.var="reflec")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RES4<-dcast(RES3, ... ~ band,
            value.var="reflec")
```

Comment: Hi! It would be better to leave some comment to explain your code. Consider that others might come here for a solution.